# javax.jms.JMSException: Duplicate durable subscription detected

Tags: spring-boot, jms

I have a JMS application deployed as a Docker image in AWS Fargate. Two services are running for the task. However the problem is I am getting this:

```
2021-03-24 05:15:43.022 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.hp.ext.cpq.pubsub.SnsTopicPublisher  : Exception happened in readJmsTopicPublishToSnsTopic --->javax.jms.JMSException: Duplicate durable subscription detected
```

This is the code I am using to create the durable subscriber:

```java
SnsTopicPublisher asyncSubscriber = this.ctx.getBean(SnsTopicPublisher.class);

            if (prop.getProperty("tibco.msgSourceType").equalsIgnoreCase("TOPIC")) {
                dest_t = session.createTopic(prop.getProperty("tibco.msgSource"));
                **TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(dest_t, "pfpDurable");**
                topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(asyncSubscriber);
                logger.debug("Set Jms Topic Listener ---> asyncSubscriber");
            }
            if (prop.getProperty("tibco.msgSourceType").equalsIgnoreCase("QUEUE")) {
                dest_q = session.createQueue(prop.getProperty("tibco.msgSource"));
                MessageConsumer msgConsumer_p = session.createConsumer(dest_q);
                msgConsumer_p.setMessageListener(asyncSubscriber);
                logger.debug("Set Jms Queue Listener ---> asyncSubscriber");
            }
```

I am getting the error for the marked line from AWS cloud watch logs.

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear. You have a "duplicate durable subscription." In other words, more than one connection is attempting to create a durable subscription using the same client ID and subscription name. You should inspect all your subscribers and ensure they are using unique client IDs and subscription names.

Comment: I understood @JustinBertram  howver there are no other app running only one instance in AWS that also mine.So is it like when one task is stopped and new task is pooled up by aws the connection may not be destroyed till the task is and at the same time another  task is pooled up by AWS fargate service but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Multiple instances of the same application is effectively the same thing as I described in my previous comment. The point is, you can't have multiple durable subscribers using the same client ID and subscription name. It's up to you to control this.

Comment: If you're using JMS 2 why not simply create a *shared* durable subscriber?

Comment: Yes @JustinBertram will try that thought but didn't use will check out using Shared durable Subscriber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a connection (and generally other JMS objects) leak. When the exception is thrown, you need to close resources in a finally {} block, similar to the JDBC pattern.

Also, you might want to look at using a Pooled Connection. This allows for open+close pattern on JMS connections without really closing connections to the server. Check out the activemq-jms-pool which is a JMS-standard pool (not ActiveMQ specific) that works with most JMS brokers, including Tibco and IBM MQ.

```
Connection connection = null;
Session session = null;
MessageConsumer messageConsumer = null;
try {
  connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
  connection.start();
  .. do some JMS
} catch (JMSException e) {
  // handle errors
} finally {
  if (messageConsumer != null) { 
      try { messageConsumer.close(); } catch (JMSException e) { logger.error("Error closing MessagingConsumer", e); 
  }
  if (session != null) { 
      try { session.close(); } catch (JMSException e) { logger.error("Error closing Session", e); 
  }
  if (connection != null) { 
      try { connection.close(); } catch (JMSException e) { logger.error("Error closing Connection", e); 
  }
}
```

Note: The JMS specification only allows 1 durable subscription per topic using the API you have in the code. The JMS v2.0 allows for a Shared Durable Subscription to support multiple consumers.

Comment: Thanks, Matt for your help I am using JMS2.0 however the problem with the closing of resources is this application will be continuously running with zero downtime so i cannot put the end code.

Comment: This is a common mistake -- closing the resources is not about shutting down the process, it is about cycling the connection and supporting reconnect on errors. Resources need to be closed to prevent leaks when the server goes down or is unavailable. The consume loop should loop over a ConnectionFactory.createConnection(), then close and refresh the connection every so often (or use a pool to automatically handle it)

Comment: Thanks, Matt sure will implement it.